# Workling not running tasks in background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, workling

I followed the [railscast](http://media.railscasts.com/videos/128_starling_and_workling.mov) that describes how to get workling running background tasks, but can't get it working. The task runs, but not in the background (it's taking 5 secs before I'm redirected to admin_path).

Here is what my code looks like:

> class AdminWorker < Workling::Base
>       def test_workling(options)
>             sleep 5
>       end
>   end
>
> class AdminController < ApplicationController
>     def test_workling
>       AdminWorker.asynch_test_workling
>       flash[:notice] = "Doing stuff in the background"
>       redirect_to admin_path
>     end
>   end

What am I doing wrong? How to debug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I had set up workling the right way:

in /config/environment.rb, I had:

`Workling::Remote.dispatcher = Workling::Remote::Runners::NotRemoteRunner.new`

while I was supposed to have:

`Workling::Remote.dispatcher = Workling::Remote::Runners::StarlingRunner.new`

It all went very smoothly after that change